# What has happened to flagging?

Tags: support, flagging

Maybe it's just a strange coincidence but I haven't seen any flags over the last days. Has there been a huge quality jump or one in flagging lazyness or are the mods on drugs (handling everything before the 10K users can see it) or was my flag assessment so bad that the system has decided better not to show them to me any more...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It changed.  See: [Notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#230726) and [Let's get rid of the 10K flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue) .  There is no more flag tab in the 10k tools.  Certain flagged posts (Not an answer among them) will be funneled into the VLQ review queue and handling them there will resolve the flags.